# Microchip C18 naked function

Tags: c, pic18, mplab-c18

Someone knows a way to declare a naked function on C18 compiler?

By naked function I mean function without any epilogue and prologue.

in gcc I use:

```
__attribute__((naked)) int func(int par1)
```

Maybe a #pragma or some trick to have the same result...??

Thank you!

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since I can't find a reference, but in my experience the compiler will leave stack handling off if a function only contains inline assembly (a `return` is still added though).